# Small pdf file turns into huge byte array

Tags: c#, itext7, .net-4.8

I'm currently working on a small app that turns text files into PDF files or the reverse. However, I want to be able to keep converted files in memory until the user presses a button to save the file (or a group of files into a .zip), all the converted files are kept in a dictionary with their old path as key and the byte array as value.

Everything was working fine except when for test purposes I took a large text files that has 12000+ lines and tried to go back and forth between text and PDF and now I'm facing a weird problem.

When going from text to PDF with this large file, everything is fine.

However, going from the PDF format of that file to text takes a huge amount of memory in the heap. Eventually going past 2 GB causing an out of memory exception.

I should note that I'm using Itext 7.

Here is the code I'm using:

**Text to PDF**

```
        public override byte[] ConvertFile(Stream stream, string path)
        {
            OnFileStartConverting(path);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
            TextFileType current = TextFileType.Parse(ext);
            MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();

            if (current.Extension.Equals(TextFileType.Txt.Extension))
            {
                resultStream = TextToPdf(stream, path);
            }
            else if (current.Extension.Equals(TextFileType.Word.Extension))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            OnFileConverted(path);
            return resultStream.ToArray();
        }

        private MemoryStream TextToPdf(Stream stream, string path)
        {
            MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            int lineCount = GetNumberOfLines(streamReader);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(resultStream);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);

            int lineNumber = 1;
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(line);
                document.Add(paragraph);
                int percent = lineNumber * 100 / lineCount;
                OnFileConverting(path, percent, lineNumber);
                lineNumber++;
            }

            document.Close();
            return resultStream;
        }
```

**PDF to Text**

```
        public override byte[] ConvertFile(Stream stream, string path)
        {
            OnFileStartConverting(path);

            string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
            TextFileType current = TextFileType.Parse(ext);
            MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();

            if (current.Extension.Equals(TextFileType.Pdf.Extension))
            {
                resultStream = PdfToText(stream, path);
            }
            else if (current.Extension.Equals(TextFileType.Word.Extension))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            resultStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            OnFileConverted(path);

            return resultStream.ToArray();
        }

        private MemoryStream PdfToText(Stream stream, string path)
        {
            MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(resultStream);

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stream);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader);
            FilteredEventListener listener = new FilteredEventListener();
            LocationTextExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy =
                listener.AttachEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
            PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener);
            int numberOfPages = pdf.GetNumberOfPages();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
            {
                parser.ProcessPageContent(pdf.GetPage(i));
                writer.WriteLine(extractionStrategy.GetResultantText());
                int percent = i * 100 / numberOfPages;
                OnFileConverting(path, percent, i);
            }

            pdf.Close();
            writer.Flush();

            return resultStream;
        }
```

**Memory usage when going from PDF to text**
[image]

The PDF file itself isn't even 1000 KB (Its 882 KB) though which is very weird to me. Am I missing something? It's even more weird considering when I try to use the converted file itself it doesn't cause any problem with memory.

Comment: You're not disposing of any of the disposable objects you create. Plus, for example in `ConvertFile()`, you're returning a byte array, so the related `TextToPdf()` should return a byte array, not a MemoryStream. Here, you have to also dispose of the MemoryStream objects you create along the way. -- Change `resultStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` in `resultStream.Position = 0;` -- Possibly, flush those byte arrays to disc, in the System Temp folder, keep just pointers and metadata in memory.

Comment: @Jimi so after a lot of refactoring and changes i managed to fix the memory issue, closing memory streams didn't help much however writing the bytes to a temporary file and just keeping the path (FileInfo) to that file solved the problem entirely. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to just *close* the MemorySteam objects, you have to Dispose() of **ALL** those objects, as the `StreamReader` and probably some (or all) the `PdfWriter` / `PdfDocument` *things* (I don't know if these have a `Dispose()` method: if they do, you **have** to call it). Possibly make use of `using` statements / nested `using` blocks to declare disposable objects: using (`var ms = new MemoryStream()) using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream); { // your code};`, etc. ). These will dispose of these objects, even if an exception is raised in that code.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah you're totally right i'm dumb, i didn't even realize that i needed to close the itext7 objects i assumed the `document.Close()` would do it for me. Turned out it wasn't at all. I'm just concerned, is it ok to have all the nested using blocks?

Comment: Of course it is, it's standard practice. Note that all objects declared with `using` statements will be disposed of *automatically*, so don't add, e.g., `streamReader.Close()` (which is the same as `Dispose()`) inside the `using` block(s). Sometimes, depending on the operations, you may need to (or find that is better to) `.Flush()` a Stream beforehand.

Comment: If you're using C# 8, you'll notice that the `using` pattern has been further *enhanced*, to provide better functionality, extended to the whole method block.

Comment: @Jimi Indeed i much prefer the using keyword with object declaration to the using block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue is in `PdfToText` which for documents with multiple pages extracts more text than is there.

The `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` does not forget its content when you start feeding a new page to it. It is not designed to be re-used across pages, you are expected to create a new instance for each page.

Re-usage in the loop in your code causes

- for `i=1` the contents of page 1 to be written to `writer`;
- for `i=2` the contents of pages 1 and 2 to be written to `writer`;
- for `i=3` the contents of pages 1, 2, and 3 to be written to `writer`;
- ...

Thus, don't re-use the text extraction strategy across pages. Instead instead move the instantiation of your `FilteredEventListener`, `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, and `PdfCanvasProcessor` into the loop to create them anew for each page.

Comment: Wow, after checking out the temp files created on runtime indeed they are very large (almost 300mb each!) and the resultant text has dups in it. i didn't realise it because it was dummy text anyway i couldn't make the diffrence in the first place. Thanks !